# with calling web services from javascript functions

Tags: javascript, xml, web-services

**while running these functions, I am calling such web service through which I have to generate session Id. 
consider url is correct

I want to know,that I am calling function from onreadystatechange.wheteher it is correct way. 
if you have another way please reply.**

function getData(_url) {

```
    var xmlhttpRequest = null;
    xmlhttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttpRequest.open("GET", _url, true);
    xmlhttpRequest.send();

    xmlhttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
        //alert(xmlhttpRequest.status);
        if(xmlhttpRequest.readyState == 4)// 4: The Request is complete
        {

            var request = xmlhttpRequest.responseXML;
            var items = request.getElementsByTagName("id")[0].firstChild.nodeValue;

            var hashcode = GetHashCode(passwordvalue + items);
            var strUrl = commonURL + 'data/' + userName + ';' + hashcode;
            data1(strUrl, 'tagname');//calling another function to generate session id
        }
    }

}


function data1(_url, _tagName) 
{
    var xmlhttpRequest = null;
    xmlhttpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttpRequest.open("GET", _url, true);
    xmlhttpRequest.send();
    xmlhttpRequest.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xmlhttpRequest.readyState == 4 && xmlhttpRequest.status==200)// 4: The Request is complete
        {

            var request = xmlhttpRequest.responseXML;
            //alert('items .....= '+ request);
            var sessionid = request.getElementsByTagName(_tagName)[0].firstChild.nodeValue;
            alert('session ID='+sessionid); 

        }
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

i would place `xmlhttpRequest.send();` after the onreadystatechange function

Also when you using the GET method you send a null value, that holds zero

Comment: I think that dosent make sense.because same think I have done using another languages i.e. java and Titanium.